# Is it a good practise to store accessToken client-side?

Tags: oauth, access-token

For a website that call a backend for each of Data through backend's API

the backend first delivers an accessToken through its authenticate handler, or the accesstoken could also be delivered with OAuth

I was wondering if then it's safe, or a bad practise, to store the accessToken as a simple Javascript var, and only make Ajax calls to the backend

thanks

Comment: Perhaps this question would make more sense if it said "use" instead of "store", as there's no real long-term or persistent storage taking place? Also, aren't there OAuth Javascript libraries for this sort of thing?

Comment: yes I don't really know OAuth,but in my case my big concern was, if the user is deconnected without closing its server session properly, anyone can access it retrieveing the accessToken (browser history, network debigger (firebg, chrome, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but make sure the accessToken is short lived. A few hours would be best.

Comment: it could mess with client's cache to frequently change it., also It seems better to keep php script and a $_SESSION['accessToken'] on server-side, the bad part, is it's not so RESTFul, since the accesstoken argument is added on the fly by those intermediate scripts